# How can combine send_file() with another information (E.g., int) in 1 response using Flask

Tags: python, flask

My problem is I'm trying to send to client and image with another additional information using Python with Flask.

I tried to use send_file(), but the issue is I can only send the image only and I can't find other ways to send the additional information with it. 
I also tried to combine the image and info into JSON, but it seems that send_file() can't be serialized as JSON

```
def post(self):
    img_path, score = self.get_result()
    final_image = send_file(
        img_path,
        mimetype='image/jpg'
    )
    output = {'img': final_image, 'score': score}
    return output
```

Is there any way that I can receive an image with additional results within 1 request from client?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can consider either of these approaches:

- Set extra information as cookie.

```
response = send_file(
                img_path,
                mimetype='image/jpg'
           )
response.set_cookies('score', score)
```

- Set additional response headers to contain extra information.

```
response = send_file(
                img_path,
                mimetype='image/jpg'
           )
response.set_header('x-myapp-score', score)
```

- Or encode the file contents in a JSON response. You can encode as base64 string or use [Concise Binary Object Representation](http://cbor.io) (Server-side library: https://github.com/brianolson/cbor_py, Client-side library: https://github.com/paroga/cbor-js)

```
from base64 import b64encode
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def post(self):
    # ...
    output = {
       'score': score
    }
    try:
        with open(final_image, 'rb') as f:
            content = f.read()
            output['img'] = b64encode(content)
    except TypeError, FileNotFoundError:
           # handle default image ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
           logger.exception('Failed to encode image file')
    return output
```